# How to compose in scheme 2 to the n factorial

Tags: scheme

Apply composition formula `(define (compose g f) (lambda (x) (g (f x))))` in order to construct  2^n! both non-tail and tail recursive implementations of functions of n! and 2^n.

For the n! and n 2 I thought

```
(define (factorial n)
  (fold * 1 (iota n 1)))
(define (two-to-the n)
  (fold * 1 (make-list n 2)))
```

how would i construct it for 2^n!?
maybe

```
(define (two-to-the factorial n )
  (fold * 1 (iota n 1)))(fold * 1 (make-list n 2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define two-to-the-factorial (compose two-to-the factorial))
```

Comment: Isn't `compose` Racket specific?

Comment: @Sylwester The OP talks about using `compose`, so clearly they'd be prepared to define it themself.

Comment: I dont think there is a compose function in scheme

Comment: @user432495 There isn't. But your post already talked about defining your own, `(define (compose f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x))))`. \*shrug\*

Comment: How can the OP not realize he had (define (compose... in his own post?

Comment: @Rptx It's probably a cut-and-paste of a homework problem. The definitions to `factorial` and `two-to-the` are actually (facetious) answers I wrote for a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24618860/13) from the OP. (You need 10k rep to see deleted posts. [Screenshot here.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qSTGt.png))

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young thanks for the screenshot. Yeah, even copy pasted your answers, didn't even read.